# Which API should we use to extract the text and images from PDF, however extracted images and text should be in sequential order?

Tags: java

I have tried PDFBox API which provides data in sequential order and iText API which provides images in sequential order. Now, my question is there a way to get both (images and text) in sequential order by using the same API ?

Answer (score 1):

iText API can be used to extract text also.

The below code can be used to get the text from PDF.

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("Test.txt");
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    PdfReader pr = new PdfReader("Test.pdf");
    int pNum = pr.getNumberOfPages();
    for (int page = 1; page <= pNum; page++) {
        String text = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(pr, page);
        bw.write(text);
        bw.newLine();
    }
bw.flush();
bw.close();
```

Hope this retrieves the text sequentially.

Comment: thanks for your valuable comment. But iText API is not extracting the text in a sequential way. This API render text on random basis and writes in a text file.